# iOS carthage with MQTT framework

Tags: ios, applet, mqtt, carthage, ios-mqtt-client-framework

I have a application which is written in objective c and using pods to set dependency and target iOS version is 7.0. Due to some license conflict i want to use MQTT with dynamic linking with help of Carthage. So I followed following steps

- Remove pod 'MQTTClient' from pod file and run the pod update.
- It removed MQTTClient and keep others pods intact like afnetworking etc.
- then I create Cartfile in project directory.
- Add Github "ckrey/MQTT-Client-Framework" in Cartfile.
- Run command carthage bootstrap --no-build --platform "iOS"
- then run carthage build --no-skip-current --platform "iOS" gives always error  Skipped building project due to the error:
  Dependency "project" has no shared framework schemes for any
  of the platforms: iOS

I have following question

Q1 As I understand, we can use both Carthage and cocoapod in same        project.
Q2 how to resolve error mention in step6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cocoapods and Carthage in the same project.

On step #6 make sure you are specifying the download as a 'binary'

Comment: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/Artifacts.md#binary-only-frameworks